# Simple python code to website

Tags: python, interface, upload, web

I am a beginner in python. For practice reasons I want to learn how to upload a python code to a website.
I have a domain and web hosting service, however I'm really confused about how to integrate my code with a
web page on my website.

(I have a decent bit of knowledge with Tkinter)
Can anybody show me how to upload this simple function to my website?:
There are two entries on the interface for the user to enter two numbers. On pressing a button a new
window(web page) with the answer displayed.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be possible to do this with some kind of JavaScript interpreter, but, AFAIK, there is no native way of running python in a web browser. If you want to do something simple like an alert on the click of a button, use JavaScript. Seriously.

Comment: Are you attempting to write client-side executable content in a language other than JavaScript? Or are you trying to execute server-side content in Python and want to know how to generate the corresponding HTML? This question is mighty vague as it stands, please [edit] the question with more details. (See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on how to improve questions.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Basics

Here is a very simple server-side Python script.  To use it, put it in your `cgi-bin` folder on your server.  (It can later be configured to run elsewhere, but `cgi-bin` usually works out of the box.)  Then change the permissions on the file via `chmod` or some Gui control.  You need to allow anyone to execute it, so `755` will do.  Then navigate to http://domain.tld/cgi-bin/myscript.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<pre>"
import os, sys
from cgi import escape
print "<strong>Python %s</strong>" % sys.version
keys = os.environ.keys()
keys.sort()
for k in keys:
    print "%s\t%s" % (escape(k), escape(os.environ[k]))
print "</pre>"
```

If that works you can move on to running more complicated scripts, using frameworks (like [web.py](http://webpy.org/)), and responding to forms.

### Form Data

To answer the actual question, we need a page with a form.  I made this from a template I use and added a form with a singe input field.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Webpage</title>
  <meta name="description" content="html5 webpage">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/test.py">
    <input name="mystuff" width="500px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Do" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice it's pointing to our `test.py` script.  That needs to be updated too so it understands our `mystuff` form element.  We throw in some error handling and import our cgi modules.  The `except` part is lazily done, but since you won't use that part of the code, I don't think it's that important.

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<pre>"

import os, sys
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

try: 
    num = int(form['mystuff'].value)
    print 'The number %d to the 13th power is %d.' % (num, num**13)
except Exception: 
    print 'What am I suposed to do with that?  This is what you call an "err
or message".  Try a number instead'

print "</pre>"
```

You should be able to go to your web-page and enter 7 in the field, which will result in a page containing...

> The number 7 to the 13th power is 96889010407.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you FakeRainBrigand for your response, I would greatly appreciate it if you can complete your answer.

Comment: Ok.  What I already posted works for you, right?  (I'll get right on it.)

Comment: @rnathani, I updated it.  That should be enough information to make your own.  Here's the [```cgi```](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) module we used.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at something like Django and mod_wsgi.

Generally helps if you have shell access to the server.